# Python re.findall with multiple patterns

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I have a text file with entries like this:

```
 Interface01 :
     adress
        192.168.0.1
next-interface:
 interface02:
     adress
        10.123.123.214
next-interface:
 interface01 :
     adress
        172.123.456.123
```

I'd like to parse it and get only the IP address corresponding to Interface01

I tried may things with python `re.finall` but couldn't get anything matching

```
 i = open(f, r, encoding='UTF-8')
 txt = i.read()
 interface = re.findall(r'Interface01 :\s*(.adress*)n',txt,re.DOTALL)
```

but nothing works.

The expected result is `192.168.0.1`.

Comment: What's that "n" at the end of the regex?

Comment: Try [`Interface01\s*:\s*adress\s+(.*)`](https://regex101.com/r/9sSdgK/1). Remove `re.DOTALL`. Use just `re.search` to get the first match. See https://ideone.com/QoE1uF. Can there be more IPs per interface?

Comment: Thanks for your help. @Maroun, The n is for the beginning of "new-interface". To Wiktor ok i try it now and tells you

Comment: Thank you very much @wiktor this solves my problem

Comment: @ricardo I posted an [answer with explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49430603/3832970).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use

```
Interface01\s*:\s*adress\s+(.*)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/9sSdgK/1). In Python, use `re.search` to get the first match since you only want to extract 1 IP address.

**Pattern details**:

- `Interface01` - a literal substring
- `\s*:\s*`  - a `:` enclosed with 0+ whitespaces
- `adress` - a literal substring
- `\s+`  - 1+ whitespaces
- `(.*)` - Group 1: any 0+ chars other than line break chars.

[Python demo](https://ideone.com/QoE1uF):

```
import re
reg = r"Interface01\s*:\s*adress\s+(.*)"

with open('filename') as f:
    m = re.search(reg, f.read())
    if m:
        print(m.group(1))

# => 192.168.0.1
```

Answer (score 2):

How about creating a pattern that said "Interface01", then skip all chars that are not digits, then get the digits and dots?

```
re.findall(r'Interface01[^0-9]+([0-9.]+)', text)
```

Result:

```
['192.168.0.1']
```

## Update

Thanks to @zipa, here is the updated regex:

```
re.findall(r'[iI]nterface01[^0-9]+([0-9.]+)', text)
```

Result:

```
['192.168.0.1', '172.123.456.123'
```

Comment: Small suggestion - change `Interface` into `[Ii]nterface`

Answer (score 0):

```
interface = re.findall(r'Interface01 :\s*.adress\s*(.*?)$',txt,re.S|re.M)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this:

```
interface = re.findall(r'Interface01 :\n +adress\n +(\d+.\d+.\d+.\d+)', txt)
# ['192.168.0.1']
```

Answer (score 0):

For getting one single match it's better to use `re.serach()` function:

```
import re

with open('filename') as f:
    pat = r'Interface01 :\s*\S+\s*((?:[0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3})'
    result = re.search(pat, f.read()).group(1)

print(result)
```

The output:

```
192.168.0.1
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use `Interface01 :\n.*?\n(.*)`